# How can I make gcloud use a specific config directory?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I would like gcloud to use a specific `.config` directory that I know the path of. Is there a way to force it to use this directory?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set the environment variable

```
CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=/path/to/dir
```

to override the default value of `~/.config/gcloud`.

Comment: Note:  you'll need to export this variable before it will take effect, even when running gcloud in the current shell.

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not sure about using a different .config dir, you can use the --configuration flag.

You can see `gcloud --help` and `gcloud topic configurations` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

First I should mention that I second Zachary's and Kevin's answers.

But if you insist on using a specific `.config` file (on linux it's actually a directory) or switching between multiple such files/dirs one way to do it would be to temporarily copy or symlink them them in the place where `gcloud` expects them. At least on linux that would be the `~/.config/gcloud` directory.

Personally I prefer symlinking in such scenarios, this works for me:

```
/home/username/.config> rm -f gcloud; ln -s gcloud.v1 gcloud
/home/username/.config> ls -l gcloud
lrwxrwxrwx 1 username at 9 Jan 19 09:19 gcloud -> gcloud.v1
/home/username/.config> gcloud auth list

No credentialed accounts.

To login, run:
  $ gcloud auth login `ACCOUNT`

/home/username/.config> rm -f gcloud ; ln -s gcloud.v2 gcloud
/home/username/.config> ls -l gcloud
lrwxrwxrwx 1 username at 9 Jan 19 09:19 gcloud -> gcloud.v2
/home/username/.config> gcloud auth list
   Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       username@gmail.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`

/home/username/.config>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem for years and was thinking of coding some great rubygem to make it happen then thought this might be a good compromise.

1. Create a simple script called `contextual-gcloud`. Note the \gcloud, fundamental for future aliasing.

```
$ cat > contextual-gcloud 
#!/bin/bash

if [ -d .gcloudconfig/ ]; then
    echo "[$0] .gcloudconfig/ directory detected: using that dir for configs instead of default."
    CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=./.gcloudconfig/ \gcloud "$@"
else
    \gcloud "$@"
fi
```

2. Add to your `.bashrc` and reload / start new bash. This will fix autocompletion.

   alias gcloud=contextual-gcloud
3. That's it! If you have a directory called that way the system will use that instead, which means you can load your configuration into source control etc.. only remember to git ignore stuff like logs, and private stuff (keys, certificates, ..).

Note: auto-completion is fixed by the alias ;)

Code: https://github.com/palladius/sakura/blob/master/bin/contextual-gcloud